# How to selectively store a variable in memory segments using C?

Tags: c, memory

We know that there are levels in memory hierarchy,
cache,primary storage and secondary storage..
Can we use a c program to selectively store a variable in a specific block in memory hierarchy?

Comment: your comments indicate you're asking about something *completely different*. so... what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comments in the other answers, I would like to add a few things.

Inside an Operating System you can not restrict in which level of the memory hierarchy your variables will be stored, since the one who controls the metal is the Operating System and it enforces you to play by its rules.

Despite this, you can do something that MAY get you close to testing access time in cache (mostly L1, depending on your test algorithm) and in RAM memory.

**To test cache access:** warm up accessing a few times a variable. Them access a lot of times the same variable (cache is super fast, you need a lot of accesses to measure access time).

**To test the main memory (aka RAM):** disable the cache memory in the BIOS and run your code.

**To test secondary memory (aka disk):** disable disk cache for a given file (you can ask your Operating System for this, just Google about it), and start reading some data from the disk, always from the same position. This might or might not work depending on how much your OS will allow you to disable disk cache (Google about it).

To test other levels of memory, you must implement your own "Test Operating System", and even with that it may not be possible to disable some caching mechanisms due to hardware limitations (well, not actually limitations...).

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Cache is designed to work transparently. Almost anything you do will end up in cache, because it's being operated on at the moment.

As for secondary storage, I assume you mean HDD, file, cloud, and so on. Nothing really ever gets stored there unless you do so explicitly, or set up a memory mapped region, or something gets paged to disk.

Comment: Well, i wanted to calculate access time for variables stored in different segments of memory.. is there an indirect way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

No. A normal computer program only has access to main memory. Even secondary storage (disk) is usually only available via operating system services, typically used via the stdio part of the library. There's basically no direct way to inspect or control the hierarchical caches closer to the CPU.

That said, there are cache profilers (like Valgrind's `massif` tool) which give you an idea about how well your program uses a given type of cache architecture (as well as speculative execution), and which can be very useful to help you spot code paths that have poor cache performance. They do this essentially by *emulating* the hardware.

There may also be architecture-specific instructions that give you some control over caching (such as "nontemporal hints" on x86, or "prefetch" instructions), but those are rare and peculiar, and not commonly exposed to C program code.

Comment: Well, i wanted to calculate access time for variables stored in different segments of memory.. is there an indirect way of doing it?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You could maybe make two versions of an algorithm, and have one of them pollute the cache aggressively and see if that makes a noticeable difference.

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing so.. but C compiler restricts the array size, am unable to populate the cache coz of that

Comment: @Insanelycurious: no offence, but you're asking the wrong questions  if you cannot even fill a cache...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific architecture and compiler that you're using.

For example, on x86/x64, most compilers have a variety of levels of prefetch instructions which hint to the CPU
that a cache-line should be moved to a specific level in the cache from DRAM (or from higher-order caches - e.g. from L3 to L2).

On *some* CPUs, non-temporal prefetch instructions are available that when combined with non-temporal read instructions, allow you to bypass the caches and read directly into a register. (Some CPUs have non-temporals implemented by forcing the data to a specific way of the cache though; so you have to read the docs).

In general though, between L1 and L2 (or L3, or L4, or DRAM) it's a bit of a black-hole. You can't specifically store a value in one of these - some caches are inclusive of each other (so if a value is in L1, it's also in L2 and L3), some are not. And the caches are designed to periodically drain - so if a write goes to L1, eventually it works its way out to L2, then L3, then DRAM - especially in multi-core architectures with strong-memory models.

You can bypass them entirely on write (use streaming-store or mark the memory as write-combining).

You can measure the different access times by:

- Using memory-mapped files as a backing store for your data (this will measure the time for *first access* to reach the CPU - just wrap it in a timer call, such as QueryPerformanceCounter or __rdtscp). Be sure to unmap and close the file from memory between each test, and turn off any caching. It'll take a while.
- Flushing the cache between accesses to get the time-to-access from DRAM.

It's harder to measure the difference between different cache levels, but if your architecture supports it, you can prefetch into a cache level, spin in a loop for some period of time, and then attempt it.

It's going to be hard to do this on a system using a commercial OS, because they tend to do a LOT of work all the time, which will disturb your measurements.